# setup.py file for building a python package

Tags: python, installation, package

What are the arguments for the setup function in setup.py file and how should I enclose these arguments in the code.
What is the significance of the description, long_description and long_description_content_type in python package.
What does an **init**.py file does ?

Comment: I suggest that you start with the [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial.

Comment: I have followed the same steps from their, but I can't understand what is long_description and content type

Answer (score 0):

The `long_description` and `long_description_content_type` fields are only necessary if you are planning to upload your package to [PyPI](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-python-package-index-pypi). The `long_description` can be just a plain text string, or it can be text formatted with some type of markdown. `long_description_content_type` is used to tell PyPI what flavor of markdown is used for long_description so that PyPI can render it correctly. This is explained in the [description](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#description) section of [Packaging and distributing projects](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/).